# unable to install ros on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 but I am not able to install ros-fuerte.
"apt-get install" yields:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1336014066~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.7-s1336006714~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.11-s1335981752~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.2-s1335952329~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.2-s1335953254~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.2-s1335953718~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1336041641~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.0-s1335952476~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1336026792~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1335976222~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.1-s1335992190~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How can I overcome this problem?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33585/unable-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That happened to me, too. I had a non-fuerte-compatible version of boost that apt-get would not install recursively for some reason.

Try to apt-get install one of the packages it's complaining about.  It'll probably give you another list of packages that it depends on.  If you keep trying to install the dependencies, it'll eventually stop complaining and install it.

In my case, installing the one boost library satisfied apt enough to install the desktop-full package without any more errors, but you might have to traverse the dependency tree a bit more.  Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

see here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/32867/ros-for-ubuntu-precise-1204

hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) with karma: 74 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1